# Open a Outlook mail compose window with HTML body from UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I'm specific about Outlook here because there is a way to do this with the native Windows Mail app. The problem is that I need to do this with Outlook which isn't a native UWP Windows app.

I'm aware of the `EmailManager` API that exists for UWP. But, as it's stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.email.emailmanager.showcomposenewemailasync?view=winrt-19041#remarks), it's not possible to use it with a HTML body.

My current workaround for the native Mail app uses the `DataTransfer` UWP API. With it I can open the Windows 10 share dialog:

```
var dtm = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
dtm.DataRequested += WindowsShare_DataRequested;
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

And in the data request event I put the HTML body into the request data like this:

```
var request = args.Request;
var deferral = request.GetDeferral();

try
{
    var htmlBody = HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(<HTML body here>);
    request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(htmlBody);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    deferral.Complete();
    var dtm = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
}
```

This works but the share dialog only shows native apps like Windows Mail.

Comment: Hello, for `DataTransfer` in UWP, only the application that has registered to receive data method will be displayed (this means that the application has the ability to process the corresponding data). Outlook does not register the corresponding method, so it cannot be displayed. Since the UWP application is a sandbox application, it is currently unable to directly communicate with a particular outlook application.

Comment: Ok thanks. But is it possible to send something like an Intent (from Android) which can be processed by a mail application? I don't need direct communication with the mail application. I just want the mail app to open a compose window with the HTML body I want.

Comment: Actually HTML mail is working with `DataManager` and the native Mail app. But that's not what I need/it's not enough. I think I have to search for another solution. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Sorry, it 's my mistake. The mail application can indeed handle HTML content. And Mail is a system application with universality. It actually does something similar to Outlook, and is also the recommended app for sending emails from UWP apps. But at present I have not found the relevant content to launch Outlook app and send email from UWP. If you have other solutions, you can write an answer and mark it, which will help more people.

Comment: Have you found a solution to launch the Outlook app yet?

Comment: No unfortunately not... Our best workaround is to attach a HTML file with the rich content to the mail. Sad but true ^^